# PhpMyAdmin 'Table does not exist on this engine' error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

so I started my laptop to work this morning and my system had just recovered from a crash. And I had to use the system restore option available on windows to start my system. After this, I started my xampp and after trying to open one of my recent databases, I got the error `table does not exist on this engine.` After checking my error log, I found a link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html. 
I have visited the link but couldn't find a useful information to solve my problem. Please help guys.

Comment: From the given link its specifies that your table is there but not recognized by InnoDB engine as it internally refers to .frm file. As told over there, please drop the table for which your getting this error message and then create it newely

Comment: And then the content of the table would be lost ?? I don't want that. Besides, its an entire database. All the tables.

Comment: did you found any solution to this

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam no i did not